# php foreach loop with array

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have the below syntax:

```
function get_outstandingchecking($db)  
{    
    $result = $db->query("  SELECT distinct(haulier) as haulier from v2loads where  adminstatus='captured' and  DATEDIFF(now(), capturedate) >4 group by haulier,DATEDIFF(now(), capturedate) order by DATEDIFF(now(), capturedate) desc  "); 
    return $result; 
}

$outstandingchecking = get_outstandingchecking($db); 
$outstandingchecking_row_count = $outstandingchecking->rowCount();

if ($outstandingchecking_row_count > 0) {
    $i=0;

    foreach ($outstandingchecking as $instance) {
        echo $instance[$i];
        $i=$i+1;
        //syntax email relevent haulier
    }
}
```

The $result query fetches an array of values(hauliers) that are affected. I then want to use each of the returned 'hauliers' and send email notifications to them.

The output shows only the first value in the query results, how can I get it to show all the values as part of the foreach loop?

Thanks as always,

Comment: What is `$db` in this case? An instance of PDO? If so, you need to call `fetch()` at some point to get the results one by one or `fetchAll()` to get an array with all results.

Comment: can u provied the result of print_r($instance);

Comment: @Till Helge Helwig, thanks I will try this, makes sense. I will revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
foreach($outstandingchecking as $instance){ 
   echo $instance[0];
}
```

You don't need $i when using foreach

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$final=array();
foreach($outstandingchecking as $instance){ 

$final[]=$instance;

$i=$i+1;

//syntax email relevent haulier

}

print_r($final);
```